# Saving a game state using serialization C++

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, save

I have a class called `Game` which contains the following:

```
vector<shared_ptr<A>> attr; // attributes
D diff; // differences
vector<shared_ptr<C>> change; // change
```

My question is, how can I write these (save) to a file and read/load it up later?
I thought about using a `struct` with these in it, and simply saving the `struct` but I have no idea where to start.

This is my attempt so far, with just trying to save `change`. I've read up a lot on the issue and my issue (well one of them, anyway) here seems to be that I am storing pointers which after closing the program would be invalid (compounded by the fact that I also free them before exiting).

```
/* Saves state to file */
void Game::saveGame(string toFile) {
    ofstream ofs(toFile, ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char *)&this->change, sizeof(C));

    /* Free memory code here */
    ....

    exit(0);
}; 

/* Loads game state from file */
void Game::loadGame(string fromFile) {
    ifstream ifs(fromFile, ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&this->change, sizeof(C));

    this->change.toString(); // display load results
};
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for serializing this data? I'd like to use only standard packages, so no `boost`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a way to write a single A or C to disk? Maybe you should work on that, first.

Comment: Is there a reason for your complicating things by using pointers at all? In any case, first write code for a single `A` and `C`, then store an element count followed by the elements. To load, read an element count and loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how is implemented classes `A`, `C` or `D`, but that is the first question: how to serialize an object of that class. For the `C` case, you need to implement something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
    // ... code to serialize c to an output stream
    return os;
}
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, C& c) {
    // ... code to populate c contents from the input stream
    return is;
}
```

or, if you prefer, create a `write()` and `read()` function for that class.

Well, if you want to serialize a `vector<shared_ptr<C>>` looks obvious you don't want to serialize the pointer, but the contents. So you need to dereference each of those pointers and serialize. If the size of the vector is not known before loading it (i.e., is not always the same), you'll need to store that information. Then, you can create a pair of functions to serialize the complete vector:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>>& vc) {
    // serialize the size of the vector using << operator
    // for each element of the vector, let it be called 'pc'
        os << *pc << std::endl; // store the element pointed by the pointer, not the pointer.
    return os;
}
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>>& c) {
    // read the size of the vector using >> operator
    // set the size of the vector
    // for each i < sizeo of the vector, let 'auto &pc = vc[i]' be a reference to the i-th element of the vector
        C c;                         // temporary object
        is >> c;                     // read the object stored in the stream
        pc = std::make_shared<C>(c); // construct the shared pointer, assuming the class C has copy constructor

    return is;
}
```

And then,

```
/* Saves state to file */
void Game::saveGame(string toFile) {
    ofstream ofs(toFile);
    ofs << change;
    ....
}; 

/* Loads game state from file */
void Game::loadGame(string fromFile) {
    ifstream ifs(fromFile);
    ifs >> change;
};
```

I know there are a lot of things you still need to resolve. I suggest you to investigate to resolve them so you understand well how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you saving pointers, you're trying to save a `shared_ptr` but using the wrong size.

You need to write serialization functions for all your classes, taking care to never just write the raw bits of a non-POD type. It's safest to always implement member-by-member serialization for everything, because you never know what the future will bring.
Then handling collections of them is just a matter of also storing how many there are.

Example for the `C`s:

```
void Game::save(ofstream& stream, const C& data)
{
    // Save data as appropriate...
}

void Game::saveGame(string toFile) {
    ofstream ofs(toFile, ios::binary);

    ofs.write((char *)change.size(), sizeof(change.size());
    for (vector<shared_ptr<C>>::const_iterator c = change.begin(); c != change.end(); ++c)
    {
        save(ofs, **c);
    }
}; 


shared_ptr<C> Game::loadC(ofstream& stream)
{
    shared_ptr<C> data(new C);
    // load the object...
    return data;
}

void Game::loadGame(string fromFile) {
    change.clear();
    size_t count = 0;
    ifstream ifs(fromFile, ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&count, sizeof(count));
    change.reserve(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        change.push_back(loadC(ifs));
    }
};
```

All the error handling is missing of course - you would need to add that.

It's actually a good idea to at least start with text storage (using `<<` and `>>`) instead of binary. It's easier to find bugs, or mess around with the saved state, when you can just edit it in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own serialization is quite a challenge. Even if you do not use boost serializatoin I would recommend you learn how to use it and comprehend how it works rather than discovering it yourself.

When serializing you finally end up with a buffer of data of which content you have very vague idea. You have to save everything you need to be able to restore it. You read it chunk by chunk. Example (not compiled, not tested and not stylish ):

```
void save(ostream& out, const string& s)
{
   out << s.size();
   out.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
}
void load(istream& in, string& s)
{
   unsigned len;
   in >> len;
   s.resize(len);
   in.read((char*)s, len); 
}

struct Game
{
   void save(ostream& out)
   {
      player.save(out);
   };
   void load(istream& in)
   {
      player.load(in);
   }
};
struct Player
{
   void save(ostream& out)
   {
       // save in the same order as loading, serializing everything you need to read it back
       save(out, name);
       save(out, experience);
   }
   void load(istream& in)
   {
       load(in, name);
       load(in, experience); // 
   }
};
```

I do not know why you would do it to yourself instead of using boost but those are some of the cases you should consider:
- type - you must figure out a way to know what "type of change" you actually have there.
- a string (vector, whatever) - size + data (then the first thing you read back from the string is the length, you resize it and copy the "length" number of characters)
- a pointer - save the data pointed by pointer, then upon deserialization you have to allocate it, construct it (usually default construct) and read back the data and reset the members to their respective values. Note: you have to avoid memory leakage.
- polymorphic pointer - ouch you have to know what type the pointer actually points to, you have to construct the derived type, save the values of the derived type... so you have to save type information
- null pointer... you have to distinguish null pointer so you know that you do not need to further read data from the stream.
- versioning - you have to be able to read a data after you added/removed a field

There is too much of it for you to get a complete answer.